# Why is there no RSS feed for /unanswered/tagged/tagname?

Tags: support, tags, unanswered-questions, feed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anyway to get a RSS feed for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42525/anyway-to-get-a-rss-feed-for-unanswered-questions)

Why isn't there an RSS feed for unanswered questions with a particular tag? For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php

I think this would be a useful feature as the pages I watch the most are the Unanswered pages with my favorite tags...

Comment: what is the timespan you give people to answer before putting it into the feed? otherwise you'd get every question.

Comment: I'm looking for a feed that shows exactly what the unanswered links already do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discussed before. I have created a solution and you can find it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42525/anyway-to-get-a-rss-feed-for-unanswered-questions/64978#64978).

Comment: Wow, more cool SO software from @George -- thanks! `:-)`

Comment: @The: Thanks! If this solves your problem, please accept this answer. (And an upvote wouldn't hurt either :) - I worked quite hard on this app.)

Comment: Sorry, it had been so long I completely forgot I'd asked this question, LOL! I checked out your code over the weekend and it works great. Nice work!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite the same thing as what you asked, but I wouldn't mind a feed for Tumbleweed questions. That would at least give questions a bit of a chance to be answered before showing up in the feed, and it wouldn't deny anyone their prized badge (because subscribers wouldn't see the question until after the badge was awarded).