# Add an RSS feed for unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, feed

I'd love to something like this implemented: `feed://stackoverflow.com/unanswered`

We use a Stack Exchange site for user support. It would be very helpful to have an RSS feed showing a status of the neglected questions about our product. For Stack Overflow, it would help get new questions answered faster.

Comment: While it't nice to see a third party solution, Stackexchange should support this natively.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be a great idea or possibly extending this to include specific tags.